# How to set default value in entity form?

Tags: forms, entities

Created an entity form with base field definition,

```
$fields['options'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('text_long')
      ->setLabel(t('Answer choices per line'))
      ->setDescription(t('Multiple answer options will be seprated by next line.'))
      ->setDisplayOptions('view', array(
        'label' => 'hidden',
        'type' => 'text_default',
        'weight' => -1,
      ))
      ->setDisplayOptions('form', array(
        'type' => 'text_textfield',
        'weight' => -1,
      ))
      ->setDisplayConfigurable('form', TRUE)
      ->setDisplayConfigurable('view', TRUE);
```

**while saving this value to database, I serialized its content and then save. But during form edit, I want unserialized data. How can I set default value in this form?**

```
class MyForm extends ContentEntityForm {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

    $form = parent::buildForm($form, $form_state);
    $entity = $this->getEntity();
    $choose = $entity->get('options')->getValue();
    foreach ($choose as $key => $value) {
      $defaultValue = unserialize($value['value']);
    }

    $form['options'] = array(
      '#default_value' => isset($defaultValue) ? $defaultValue : '',
    );
    $entity = $this->entity;
    return $form;
  }
```